# (MongoLab) MongoException, com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Autherticator Error

Tags: java, android, mongodb, mlab

I am using `mongolab` service and made my account there and also created one `database`. I successfully integrated local MongoDB with android and now trying to connect my android app with the mongolab and i followed the preliminary instructions provided on net. My Code

```
String textUri = "mongodb://xyz:MyPass_XYZ@ds023288.mongolab.com:23288/sample";

    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(textUri);
    MongoClient m = new MongoClient(uri);
    DB d=m.getDB("sample");
    DBCollection collection = d.getCollection("mycollection");
```

But i get runtime exception that

> com.mongodb.MongoException:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I studied and found that `NoClassDefFounderror` comes when the specifies file is not present. The file is

> com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Autheticaor$ScramSha1SaslClient

I checked `mongoDB` website and found that they upgraded and new `mongo` needs `SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication`. [Upgrading Link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/)

My `mongoshell` is using mongoversion `3.2.1` and mongolab version is `3.0.9`. As `SCRAM-SHA-1` started from `3.0` so this has to be no problem. Also `3.0.9` is compatible with `3.2.1`. [MongoDB Versions Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility)

Any idea how can i solve this problem.

Comment: I think you need to update the version of your Java driver, not the mongo shell. Please make sure that the Java driver version adheres to the minimum requirement as listed here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else dealing with same problem, here is the answer. Use these android drivers. 
Important: No driver-async is not ported because `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel` doesn't exist on Android and doesn't exist any porting.

[New Android Drivers](https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver)